# Car steering wheel question

Tags: steering-wheel

When you turn your car steering wheel, does it turn all four wheels or two wheels in front or at the back? How can you learn to steer properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  However, *most* cars turn the 2 wheels at the front.  A few turn all 4 (typically the rear steer portion is much smaller angle than front though).  Rear only steering is very rare, typically just seen in task specific trucks.

As far as learning how to steer properly, practice...

Comment: Nissan GTR he he he he :-)

Comment: Mitsubishi 3000GT VR4 as well.